# Segmentation fault with Quick sort

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, quicksort

I need to implement a quick sort for my university assignment. The following is the implementation for quick sort that I wrote in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, std::size_t S>
void quick_forward_order(T(&container)[S], std::size_t lower_bound = std::size_t(0), std::size_t upper_bound = S - 1)
{
    if(lower_bound >= upper_bound)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Choosing the last element as the pivot
    const T& pivot_element = container[upper_bound];

    std::size_t rhs_pointer = upper_bound;
    std::size_t lhs_pointer = lower_bound;

    while (lhs_pointer < rhs_pointer)
    {
        while(container[lhs_pointer] <= pivot_element && lhs_pointer < rhs_pointer)
        {
            ++lhs_pointer;
        }

        while(container[rhs_pointer] >= pivot_element && rhs_pointer > lhs_pointer)
        {
            --rhs_pointer;
        }

        std::swap(
            container[lhs_pointer],
            container[rhs_pointer]
        );
    }

    std::swap(
        container[lhs_pointer],
        container[upper_bound]
    );

    quick_forward_order(container, lower_bound, lhs_pointer - 1);
    quick_forward_order(container, lhs_pointer + 1, upper_bound);
};

template<typename T, std::size_t S>
void quick_reverse_order(T(&container)[S], std::size_t lower_bound = std::size_t(0), std::size_t upper_bound = S - 1)
{
    if(lower_bound >= upper_bound)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Choosing the last element as the pivot
    const T& pivot_element = container[upper_bound];

    std::size_t rhs_pointer = upper_bound;
    std::size_t lhs_pointer = lower_bound;

    while (lhs_pointer < rhs_pointer)
    {
        while(container[lhs_pointer] >= pivot_element && lhs_pointer < rhs_pointer)
        {
            ++lhs_pointer;
        }

        while(container[rhs_pointer] <= pivot_element && rhs_pointer > lhs_pointer)
        {
            --rhs_pointer;
        }

        std::swap(
            container[lhs_pointer],
            container[rhs_pointer]
        );
    }

    std::swap(
        container[lhs_pointer],
        container[upper_bound]
    );

    quick_reverse_order(container, lower_bound, lhs_pointer - 1);
    quick_reverse_order(container, lhs_pointer + 1, upper_bound);
};
```

This is the code that I tried and tested this with:

```
int main(void)
{
    int array[5] = {3, 1, 5, 7, 6};
    
    std::cout << "Before sorting:" << "\n\n";
    
    for(std::size_t index = 0; index < 5; ++index)
    {
        std::cout << array[index] << "\n";
    }
    
    std::cout << std::flush;
    
    
    quick_forward_order(array);
    
    
    std::cout << "After sorting:" << "\n\n";
    
    for(std::size_t index = 0; index < 5; ++index)
    {
        std::cout << array[index] << "\n";
    }
    
    std::cout << std::flush;
    
    return (0);
}
```

I keep getting a segmentation fault around this line for each of the methods:

```
while(container[lhs_pointer] <= pivot_element && lhs_pointer < rhs_pointer)
```

I can't figure out what the problem is though. Does it have to do with the fact that I am using an `std::size_t` and it goes into the negatvie? If so, then how can I fix this please?

Comment: Looks like your guess is correct. https://godbolt.org/z/ndx35qW4j

Comment: In the future, you can use a error checks, asserts, exceptions, the debugger and/or logging to find these kinds of errors.  For example if you added a check for the values of lhs and rhs being <0 or >= the initial array size you could output a log message, throw an exception, have a breakpoint set inside the code that runs when the test fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full debug log:

```
Process 12582 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1d6fdfe67c)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003148 test`void quick_forward_order<int, 5ul>(container=0x000000016fdfe7c0, lower_bound=0, upper_bound=12884901893) [5ul], unsigned long, unsigned long) at test.cpp:26:12
   23         ++lhs_pointer;
   24       }
   25
-> 26       while (container[rhs_pointer] >= pivot_element &&
   27              rhs_pointer > lhs_pointer) {
   28         --rhs_pointer;
   29       }
Target 0: (test) stopped.
```

You can see access violation because `upper_bound` is too big, and your guess is correct. Once a type of `size_t` of value `0` decrease by `1`, its value will be set to the largest integer value that can be represented in that large space.

And if we continue debug:

```
(lldb) bt <============ print calling sequence, which is backtrace(bt)
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1d6fdfe67c)
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100003148 test`void quick_forward_order<int, 5ul>(container=0x000000016fdfe7c0, lower_bound=0, upper_bound=12884901893) [5ul], unsigned long, unsigned long) at test.cpp:26:12
    frame #1: 0x00000001000031f0 test`void quick_forward_order<int, 5ul>(container=0x000000016fdfe7c0, lower_bound=0, upper_bound=1) [5ul], unsigned long, unsigned long) at test.cpp:36:3
    frame #2: 0x00000001000031f0 test`void quick_forward_order<int, 5ul>(container=0x000000016fdfe7c0, lower_bound=0, upper_bound=2) [5ul], unsigned long, unsigned long) at test.cpp:36:3
    frame #3: 0x00000001000031f0 test`void quick_forward_order<int, 5ul>(container=0x000000016fdfe7c0, lower_bound=0, upper_bound=4) [5ul], unsigned long, unsigned long) at test.cpp:36:3
    frame #4: 0x0000000100002f1c test`main at test.cpp:86:3
    frame #5: 0x000000018ed2d058 dyld`start + 2224
```

Let's check frame 3, which is the first time you call `quick_forward_order`:

```
(lldb) f 3 <======= frame 3
frame #3: 0x00000001000031f0 test`void quick_forward_order<int, 5ul>(container=0x000000016fdfe7c0, lower_bound=0, upper_bound=4) [5ul], unsigned long, unsigned long) at test.cpp:36:3
   33
   34     std::swap(container[lhs_pointer], container[upper_bound]);
   35
-> 36     quick_forward_order(container, lower_bound, lhs_pointer - 1);
   37     quick_forward_order(container, lhs_pointer + 1, upper_bound);
   38   };
   39
(lldb) p lhs_pointer <==== print lhs_pointer
(size_t) $0 = 3
```

And then frame 2 and 1:

```
(lldb) f 2 <======== frame 2
frame #2: 0x00000001000031f0 test`void quick_forward_order<int, 5ul>(container=0x000000016fdfe7c0, lower_bound=0, upper_bound=2) [5ul], unsigned long, unsigned long) at test.cpp:36:3
   33
   34     std::swap(container[lhs_pointer], container[upper_bound]);
   35
-> 36     quick_forward_order(container, lower_bound, lhs_pointer - 1);
   37     quick_forward_order(container, lhs_pointer + 1, upper_bound);
   38   };
   39
(lldb) p lhs_pointer <===== print lhs_pointer
(size_t) $1 = 2      <===== start decreasing because we pass lhs_pointer - 1
(lldb) f 1           <===== frame 1
frame #1: 0x00000001000031f0 test`void quick_forward_order<int, 5ul>(container=0x000000016fdfe7c0, lower_bound=0, upper_bound=1) [5ul], unsigned long, unsigned long) at test.cpp:36:3
   33
   34     std::swap(container[lhs_pointer], container[upper_bound]);
   35
-> 36     quick_forward_order(container, lower_bound, lhs_pointer - 1);
   37     quick_forward_order(container, lhs_pointer + 1, upper_bound);
   38   };
   39
(lldb) p lhs_pointer
(size_t) $2 = 0
```

Ops. You can see `lhs_pointer` is `0` now. Once you pass it as `lhs_pointer - 1`.... Now everything is clear.

And as for solution, that's really simple: swap `size_t` with `int` in your interface. Yes, that's all:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t S>
void quick_forward_order(T (&container)[S], int lower_bound = 0,
                         int upper_bound = S - 1)
```

And the protection at the beginning of your function will start to work.

```bash
❯ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
❯ ./test
Before sorting:

3
1
5
7
6
After sorting:

1
3
5
6
7
```

If you really want a `size_t` implementation, that's easy ,too: Before you call `quick_forward_order` function, judge if `lhs_pointer` is `0`, if it is, stop calling `quick_forward_order`

Comment: Thank you. Your solution by having a check before calling the recursive function again works perfectly. The only reason why I prefer to have `std::size_t` instead of `int` is because the community keeps pushing me towards using `std::size_t` because it is large enough to accommodate for big number of elements. otherwise, I have no problem just sticking with the `int` type.

Comment: @Default Another reason why to use `std::size_t`: please check [value type part of the document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), this will be really helpful in metaprogramming. Using `size_t` is a really good habit, keep it on!

Comment: Will do! Thank you for the motivation!